# Proper binding of $(this) when extracting named function in .on() callback

Tags: jquery

I have a snippet of code like this and everything works great:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document)
        .on('click', '[selector]', function(e) {
            const paramAttr = $(this).attr('data-set-param')
            $(this).addClass('some-class').attr('checked', true)
            ...
        })
})
```

I want to add another event handler but reuse the initial callback so I start by extracting it out to a function like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document)
        .on('click', '[selector]', setClickHandler)

    function setClickHandler(event) {
        const paramAttr = $(this).attr('data-set-param')
        $(this).addClass('some-class').attr('checked', true)
        ...
    }
})
```

I tested the above and everything still works. Now, I add another event handler:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document)
        .on('click', '[selector]', setClickHandler)
        .on('keypress', '[selector]', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                setClickHandler(e)
            }
        })

    function setClickHandler(event) {
        const paramAttr = $(this).attr('data-set-param')
        $(this).addClass('some-class').attr('checked', true)
        ...
    }
})
```

At this point, when doing an enter key press, I get errors when accessing the contenst of the `$(this)` variable. How do I go about doing the proper binds or calls so that `$(this)` can be accessed properly in the function call?

Comment: Use `event.currentTarget` in the second function.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? Is there a solution that uses jQuery (as this is the legacy system that I'm working in)?

Comment: There's no way to pass along `this` automatically. The alternative is to pass `this` as an extra argument to the function.

Comment: How is it that in my second example, `$(this)` was able to be inferred/passed when simply using the callback as a named function?

Comment: Because jQuery binds `this` when calling the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.call()` to pass a `this` context when calling a function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document)
        .on('click', '[selector]', setClickHandler)
        .on('keypress', '[selector]', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                setClickHandler.call(this, e)
            }
        })

    function setClickHandler(event) {
        const paramAttr = $(this).attr('data-set-param')
        $(this).addClass('some-class').attr('checked', true)
        ...
    }
})
```

Comment: Perfect, this helps me out. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe more typically written `setClickHandler.call(this, e)`, if it helps anyone.